# Converting from spherical coordinates to cartesian around arbitrary vector $N$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

So if I'm given an arbitrary unit vector $N$ and another vector $V$ defined in spherical coordinates $\theta$ (polar angle between $N$ and $V$) and $\phi$ (azimuthal angle) and $r = 1$. How do I convert vector $V$ into cartesian coordinates?

Now, I know that in general the conversion from spherical to cartesian is as follows:

$$x = r  \sin \theta  \cos \phi$$ 
$$y = r \sin \theta \sin \phi $$
$$z = r \cos \theta$$

However, since the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ are defined respective to the vector $N$ and not the axes, the above conversion wouldn't work, yes? So how would I go about modifying the conversion?

Comment: The vector $N$ does not define a coordinate system. Please explain how $V$ is defined relative to $N$. For example what plane is the $\phi$ angle defined in?

Answer (score 1):

This is not well defined. You really need three vectors to define the spherical coordinate system. With only $ n $, how do you decide where $ \phi = 0 $ is?

Anyway, suppose that you do have an orthonormal basis $ e_1, e_2, e_3 = n $. Then you can write V as $ x e_1 + y e_2 + z e_3 $, where $ x,y,z $ are given by the formula you gave. If you have the Cartesian coordinates of $ e_1, e_2, e_3 $, then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

[image: Spherical coordinates from reference frame]

If so, you can use formulas I definitely know to extract the original angles from $M$ and then add $\theta$ to the polar angle and $\phi$ to the azimuthal angle, and then use the standard spherical conversion to express it in Cartesian coordinates.